# Why do the residents of The Ark/Arkadia think 'blood must have blood' is uncivilized and violent?

Tags: the-100

Nearly all the Ark folks seem to dislike the idea of '*blood must have blood*' because it is too violent, or they see it as indicative of the violent nature of the grounder. This seems strange since they were a community that killed anyone for any wrong doing. Their saying could basically be "Anything bad must have blood". It seems like they're much more violent than the grounders.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that people living in a finite space like a space station might need to consider population controls? Nothing says population control like capital punishment.

Comment: not saying it's not necessary. Just that it seems a lot more extreme than the grounders kind of justice.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like 'Blood must have blood' is more of a revenge motive, whereas people of the Ark use death as a punishment, more of a justice system.